# Difference Between %f and %F in printf()?

Tags: c++, c

I noticed that [printf()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) has specifiers `%F` and `%f`.

What are the differences?  The link above says `%F` will give "Decimal floating point, uppercase".

I fail to see what an uppercase floating point is.

Thanks!

Comment: `1.0e+7` versus `1.0E+7`.

Comment: @Eljay `%f` and `%F` never use exponential notation, no?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat • I stand corrected.  I realized I haven't used `printf` in a very long time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Per the C 2018 standard, clause 7.21.6.1, paragraph 8:

> The F conversion specifier produces INF, INFINITY, or NAN instead of inf, infinity, or nan, respectively.

Answer (score 9):

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string#Type_field) :

> f and F only differs in how the strings for an infinite number or NaN
>   are printed (inf, infinity and nan for f; INF, INFINITY and NAN for F )

Example :

```
double result = 1.0/0.0;
printf("%f\n%F\n",result,result);
//inf
//INF
```